# image onload not firing javascript when source is base64 websocket data

Tags: javascript, python, canvas, websocket, base64

I have a Custom helpdesk application that I am trying to run in javascript.
the program has a peice of code that runs on the customer's computer and sends an image to a autobahn websocket server which acts as a proxy to a image viewer which can send clicks and keystrokes back over the websockets. this is all currently working in python correctly however, when i try it in javascript, I cannot get my image loaded no matter what I do and I can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

This is the part of my javascript that is broken:

```
function onMessage(evt) {
  if(evt.data.indexOf('[00000]')>=0){
    var ar = evt.data.split('[00000]');
    if (ar[0] == "[IMAGE]"){
      var imgdata = evt.data.split('[22222]');
      context.width = imgdata[0];
      context.height = imgdata[1];
      console.log(context.width + " " + context.height)
      try{
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgdata[2];
        context.drawImage(img,0,0);
        console.log("IMAGE");
      }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
      }
    }else if(ar[0] == "[RETCONN]"){
       console.log("Accepted!");
    }
  }
}
```

Below is some code from the server to try and clarify what is going on with the javascript.

```
def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
    if isBinary:
        print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
    else:
        msg = payload.decode('utf8')
        com, data, arg = msg.split('[11111]')
        if com == ("[IMAGE]"):
            for name, conn in clients.items():
                if name == data:
                    conn.sendMessage(('[IMAGE]'+'[00000]'+arg).encode('utf8'))
                    break
```

and this is how the image is put together from the customer side:

```
data = image.tostring()
data = base64.b64encode(data)
self.sendMessage(('[IMAGE]' + '[11111]' + rid + '[11111]' + str(w) + '[22222]' + str(h) + '[22222]' + data).encode('utf8'))
```

Anyone have any ideas how what i am doing wrong in my javascript?

EDIT: i am aware that img.src is in the wrong location. moving to the right spot does not fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use base64 encoded image as a source for the image object, it needs to be in format:

```
data:image/png;base64,<base64 encoded image>
```

You need to prepend `data:image/png;base64,` to your base64 string

```
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,"+imgdata[2];
```

You are also parsing your messages wrong.
`imgdata[0]` is supposed to be your width, but it also includes `[IMAGE][00000]`.
You probably want `ar[1].split('[22222]');` instead of `evt.data.split('[22222]');`.

To avoid complications with encoding, I would recommend you to use JSON to encode your WebSocket messages.

**Edit:**

You are getting a broken image because `image.tostring()` returns raw image data, but with `data:image/png;base64,` it's expected to be in PNG format.

To get base64 encoded PNG data use this:

```
import io
buffer = io.BytesIO()
image.save(buffer, "png")
data = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: changing those allows data to flow but the image i recieve is broken.

Comment: i hacked my way around this temporaliy using a  peice of middleware heavily modifed from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595130/javascript-html5-canvas-display-from-python-websocket-server?rq=1 becuase of image corruption but i know i really should not need to.

Comment: @arumator I think I found your problem with the broken image. See my edit.